# PHP Regex - accept all positive numbers except for 1

Tags: php, regex

Regexes and I have a relationship of love and hate. I need to match (accept) all numbers except for number 1 and 0. Seeing it as math and not string, number >= 2 should be matched. Also please consider this is part of a Zend route param (reqs) so I have to go with regex unless I want to extend Route class, and etc. etc. :)

```
103 => 103
013 => 013
201 => 201
340 => 340
111 => 111
001 => no match
010 => 010
100 => 100
  1 => no match
000 => no match
 00 => no match
  0 => no match
```

I've tried some variations of `[^1][|\d+]` (trying to nail one digit at a time :D) but so far I've failed horribly :(

Nailed it!!

The regex I was looking for appears to be the following

```
^([2-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{1,})$
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude patterns with all zeroes that optionally end in an one:

```
/^(?!0*1?$)\d+$/
```

If you read it without the parens, this regex matches anything that consists of one or more decimal digits. The parens contain an assertion that causes the regex to match only if the pattern `0*1?$` *cannot* be matched beginning at the start of the input, so this removes the scenario of all zeroes and one with any number of prepended zeroes.

Comment: This looks promising but should also match 11, 111, etc. Seeing it as numbers (not as strings with digits), any positive number over 1 (number >= 2) should be matched. Plus, I have to use regex 'cause it's validation for a parameter in a Zend route :(

Comment: Then you can change the lookahead into: `(?!0*1?0*$)`

Comment: @ptheofan: So, it should reject all combinations of ones and zeroes but accept "all ones"? It's not too clear what the goal is (you might also want to improve the question title).

Comment: in plain math (consider number as a numerical value and not a series of characters), the regex should match number >= 2. Something like (\d+) >= 2.

Comment: @ptheofan: So why do the examples state that `010` and `100` should not match?

Comment: oh! Sorry, my bad. Will correct it. btw, so far the best I've reached is ^([2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{1,})$ which unfortunately will not match single digit numbers

Comment: @ptheofan: Updated the answer. But it's really really *really* counter-intuitive to do this validation with a regex instead of writing it in an easily understandable form: `ctype_digit($param) && $param > 1`.

Comment: The alternative would be to extend Zend_Controller_Router_Route. I really don't like Zend either... Yii ftw :D

Answer (score 2):

Use negation on the result for matching all zeroes and ones

```
if(!preg_match("^[01]+$",$string)) {...}
```

Comment: be sure to check that it only contains them, currently 01 + will match anywhere

Comment: Can't actually do my own if in that place. It's a regex I need to use in a zend route for parameter validation. Plus, 11, 111, etc should also be valid - updated the example patterns also

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking of it the wrong way.

```
^[01]+$
```

will match all that onyl contain 0 or 1.

If that matches reject it, if it doesnt match check its a valid number and you should have a match

Answer (score 0):

```
//if the numbers only include  0 or 1 reurn false;else will return the numbers
function match_number($number){
    if(preg_match("/^[01]*$/", $number) > 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return $number;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match any number (not digits, but number as a whole) >= 2

```
^([2-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{1,})$
```

Thanks for all the valuable help in the answers, some were really helpful and helped me reach the desired result.

Comment: It won't match 013 and 010 from your examples above.